# How would I vertically align these two divs in the middle of its parent?

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have the following code and I want to align the title and category divs in the middle:

```css
.grid-item-info {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    opacity: 0;
    color: #333333;
}
.grid-item:hover .grid-item-info {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.grid-item .title,
.grid-item .category {
    width: 46%;
    float: left;
}
.grid-item .title {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 2%;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
    @include heading(16px,400);
}
.grid-item .category {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    @include heading(16px,300);
}
```

```html
    <div class="grid-item">
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="grid-item-info">
       <div class="title">
        Title
       </div><!-- end .title -->
       <div class="category">
        Category
       </div><!-- end .category -->
      </div><!-- end. grid-item-info -->
      <img src="img...">
     </div><!-- end .col-md-4 -->
    </div><!-- end .grid-item -->
```

What I want to do is vertically align the title and category divs inside the grid-item-info div. How do I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centering vertically is often a challenge in HTML.  One of the best methods I have found is making use of the CSS `vertical-align:center;`

If you add a div that will be 100% height inside of your `.grid-item-info` div and remove the `float`, we could accomplish what you're looking for like this:

```
<div class="grid-item">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="grid-item-info">
      <div class="title">
        Title
      </div><!-- end .title -->
      <div class="category">
        Category
      </div><!-- end .category -->
      <div class="vcenter"></div><!-- end .vcenter -->
    </div><!-- end. grid-item-info -->
    <img src="img...">
  </div><!-- end .col-md-4 -->
</div><!-- end .grid-item -->

.grid-item .title,
  .grid-item .category {
  width: 46%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:center;
}
.grid-item .vcenter {
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/n2y8wpwt/

Comment: Thank you - this worked for me, but why does there have to be a vcenter, why can't those CSS properties be on the grid-item-info?

Comment: When you use `display:inline-block;vertical-align:center;`, it is aligning all the `inline` items vertically.  Because the `grid-item-info` is not one of the items inside of itself, the CSS you apply to it will not change the alignment of the items inside of it.  But, like I did, you can add a div that will fill its full height, aligned vertically, and all items will now be vertically-aligned with each other.  Let me know if that makes sense to you.

Comment: That does make sense. Thank you very much for the answer and for explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the method I have been using.

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-o-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
top: 50%;
position: relative;
```

Apply to .title and .category

Comment: This method will work well if you can afford to support only IE9+ http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't usually support IE8 and below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'display: table' to achieve vertical alignment.

I have edited your code here > https://jsfiddle.net/q5o9ubxn/

What you can do, is display the parent div as 'table' and then place a child div inside of that displayed 'table-cell' and set the alignment to middle.

```
.styleTable {
    display: table; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.styleCell {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<div class="grid-item">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="grid-item-info styleTable">
            <div class="styleCell">
                <div class="title">
                    Title
                </div><!-- end .title -->
                <div class="category">
                    Category
                </div><!-- end .category -->
            </div>
        </div><!-- end. grid-item-info -->
        <img src="img..." />
    </div><!-- end .col-md-4 -->
</div><!-- end .grid-item -->
```